# Xamarin.Forms GoogleMaps - : 'API key not found. check that ... is an element of AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: c#, api, xaml, xamarin.forms, nuget

Hello StackOverFlow community,

I'm following a course on Pluralsight titled 'Integrating Google Maps into Xamarin.Forms Apps'.

I've followed all of the steps required - and I've just added the maps control. I've configured the maps on my Android file as you can see below:

```
using System;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content.PM;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;

namespace standard.Droid
{
    [Activity(Label = "standard", Icon = "@mipmap/icon", Theme = "@style/MainTheme", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation | ConfigChanges.UiMode | ConfigChanges.ScreenLayout | ConfigChanges.SmallestScreenSize )]
    public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
            ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            Xamarin.FormsGoogleMaps.Init(this, savedInstanceState); // configured here

            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            LoadApplication(new App());
        }
        public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, [GeneratedEnum] Android.Content.PM.Permission[] grantResults)
        {
            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

            base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }
    }
}
```

Manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" package="com.companyname.standard" android:installLocation="preferExternal">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21" android:targetSdkVersion="28" />
    <application android:label="standard.Android" android:theme="@style/MainTheme"></application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application android:label="standard.Android">
        <meta-data android:name="com.companyname.standard" android:value="(my api key)" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

I've generated my keystore - I've followed all of the steps as required. And I get this message:

```
: 'API key not found.  Check that <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" android:value="your API key"/> is in the <application> element of AndroidManifest.xml
```

This is my XAML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:maps="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.GoogleMaps;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.GoogleMaps" 
             x:Class="standard.MainPage">

    <StackLayout>
        <maps:Map />
    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

I've got no idea why this is happening - I've followed instructions as needed. Maybe I am missing something?

And yes this seems to be related to Google Maps as when I remove the XAML code it works perfectly.

Again, I get this message:

```
: 'API key not found.  Check that <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" android:value="your API key"/> is in the <application> element of AndroidManifest.xml
```

Thanks,

tommy99

**EDIT: and for anyone saying 'oh put it in an application element', here's my reponse: yes I've tried that and it still is not working...**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your manifest file has **TWO** `<application />` elements.  You need to combine them.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" package="com.companyname.standard" android:installLocation="preferExternal">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21" android:targetSdkVersion="28" />
    <application android:label="standard.Android" android:theme="@style/MainTheme">
      <meta-data android:name="com.companyname.standard" android:value="AIzaSyBSb23cDhglvJf3aZXYPKNV4aSPt6RTLns" />
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
</manifest>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer but I tried this and I am getting the same error.

Comment: read the error message - you do not have `android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"`.  It is also not a good idea to post your API key on a public forum

Comment: OK it works now thanks for the answer I won't post my api key on a public forum next time

Comment: can you remove my api key from your answer for privacy reasons

Comment: I deleted the api key so it can't be used... thanks anyways